# Javascript - Does not save into database when i change value in javascript side

Tags: javascript, html, css, postgresql

My code looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("medewerkers").value = mdwString;
    document.getElementById("medewerkersomschr").value = mdwNaam;

    $("#medewerkers").val(mdwString);
    $("#medewerkersomschr").val(mdwNaam);

    document.getElementById("machines").value = mchString;
    document.getElementById("machinesomschr").value = mchNaam;

    $("#machines").val(mchString);
    $("#machinesomschr").val(mchNaam);
```

As u can see i tried two ways to get a value into fields.

This does work for me, but next up when i try to save the values into the database it goes wrong. It looks like the view got updated but not the value of the html itself. Does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong or what i should change up?

Comment: `when i try to save the values into the database it goes wrong` - it would be very helpful to see how you are attempting this, as all the code you've shown is client side, putting values into presumably input elements - there is nothing to indicate how you are sending the data to the database

Comment: where's your server side code that puts the values into the db?